# Stock set to zero after sale

Tags: stock, inventory, magento2.4.2

Magento 2.4.2
For some reason product stock is being set to 0 after an order is placed, regardless of quantity previously in stock or quantity ordered.

What could be causing this?

How can I debug where the error is coming from?

Is this likely to be a code error or some database error?

The site has recently been moved server, anything I should look out for here?

Answer (score 0):

You can debug the problem by adding this event

```
cataloginventory_stock_item_save_before
```

The aim is, compare the quantity before and after place an order:

```
$stockItemOld = $this->stockItemRepository->get($stockItem->getId());
$beforeQty = $stockItemOld->getQty();
```

Then use this event `cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after`, to get the quantity after it changed:

```
$stockItem  = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();
$stockItem->getData('qty');
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try